# Calling Cakephp3 Flash Messages from Template

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm working on Ajax request in cakephp3 and need to display a flash success message to user on success.

Here is what i'm doing:

```
$('#validate-btn').on('click', function () {
        $('#validate-btn').text("Validating...");
        $('#results-form').submit();
        if (ids.length !== 0) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo Cake\Routing\Router::url(array("controller" => "results", "action" => "validateSelected"));?>" + "/" + JSON.stringify(ids),
                cache: false,
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#validate-btn').text("Validate Selected");
                    <?php $this->Flash->success("Validated"); ?>
                },
                error: function (data) {
                    alert('s');
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Everything else is working fine but the flash message. How can i display cakephp3's flash messages inside view?

Here is my how i get the request from controller via ajax:

```
echo $query->execute()? true : false;
```

Comment: You can use [Flash](https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-flash) plugin which provides transient flash messages that can be set from helper/view context. This seems to be exactly what you need. The important part is that those do not go/leak into session and other pages (as they should be scoped to this template/layout only).

Answer (score 0):

Flash messages are not for json response.

You should do the follwoing.

In your controller:

```
$result = $query->execute();
if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
    $this->set(compact('result'));
    $this->set('_serialize', 'result');
    return;
}
```

Calling set at _serialize crates a json response without the need to create a corresponding json template for this controller method.

In your js file

```
success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //the result is available as jqXHR.responseJSON
}
```

Comment: All I'm doing is sending my controller an array of ID's, it updates the data and returns true or false. I didn't got how i'll display a message to user about success or failure?

Comment: What is not clear in my answer? If $result is a boolean you can create a message based on that at the javascript, at the same line in my example. Use Firebug, add a breakpoint there and check your jqXHR object.

Comment: You mean i have to use some external JS Lib for displaying flash messages ? My question was is it possible to display Cakephp3 flash helper there?

Comment: @SubhanAhmed yes. That is the way.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something as below:

**In the Controller::**

```
   if ($this->XYZ->save($eventEntity)) {
            $this->Flash->success(['message' => __('Updated the Event'), 'title' => __('Success')]);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('An Error occurred while updating the event. Please try again'));
        }
```

**In the Ajax::**

```
     $.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                                            async: true,
                                            url: $("#xyz").attr("data-confirm"),
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            success: function (response) {
                                                 toastr.success(response.message, response.title);
                                            },
                                            error: function (data) {
                                                toastr.error(data.message, data.title);
                                            }
                                        });
```

I'm using toaster plugin but you can use any flash of your choice. The message will be available in your response.message

Answer (score 0):

Another way set layout "ajax" in the controller and in layout/ajax.ctp:
Add `echo $this->Flash->render();`